# How to concatenate "1 " in front of many cells at once on a Google Sheets doc?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

I am trying to concatenate many cells of a Google Sheets with "1 " in front of every cell.  There are 360 cells so changing each individually would be a difficult task.

Comment: If this is something to be done once, just put a formula ="1 "&A1 somewhere, extend to a large enough range, then copy the results and paste special - only the values - back into original range.

Comment: @NormalHuman thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-time replacement like this, an easy thing to do is to carry out the computation elsewhere on the sheet (or in another sheet), and then copy-paste the *values* back in.

1. Put the formula `="1 "&A1` somewhere.
2. Extend it to a large enough range so that it processes all of your data.
3. Cut the results:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or its equivalent on Mac.
4. Paste *values only* back to the original range: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> or its equivalent.